# How can I autorun a python script as soon as a USB device is plugged in?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I wrote a program for my friend's birthday with python and I put a gift card code and a congrats inside it but I want to make it autorun my script when I plug my USB in my friend's laptop.

I want to surprise him.

Comment: Is python installed in your friends pc?

Comment: @Dinesh Yes we program togather

Comment: What OS? Windows used to have autorun.inf but removed it because, surprisingly, it was used for malicious purposes.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yes windows, you meen its impossible??? U Sure??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commenter [@Johnny Mopp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669576/johnny-mopp) is right; you used to be able to place a file named `autorun.inf` on any drive and have Windows execute any file it referenced. However, this is no longer possible.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorun.inf#Abuse):

> Autorun.inf has been used to execute a malicious program automatically, without the user knowing.[2][3][4][5] This functionality was removed in Windows 7 and a patch for Windows XP and Vista was released on August 25, 2009 and included in Microsoft Automatic Updates on February 8, 2011

However, there is still a market for devices that *look like a USB flash drive*, but are in fact recognized by the computer as a *USB keyboard*. These devices can issue any pre-programmed keystrokes upon inserting them, for instance `Windows-R` followed by `cmd` and any malicous commands that you'd like to run on the command line. One such device is the [Rubber Ducky](https://shop.hak5.org/products/usb-rubber-ducky-deluxe).

Perhaps you could use something like this to fool your friend?